# Invalid multinomial distribution (encountering probability entry < 0) at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorRandom.cpp:325

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a `PyTorch` tensor called `out_probs` which is produced like this:

```
out_probs=F.softmax(out_dec[:,0],dim=0)
```

Also, the shape of `out_probs` is `[128,20004]`

`out_probs` is the result of a softmax operation and it's not supposed to contain any negative value so naturally the result of `out_probs[out_probs<0` is going to be an empty tensor(actually I checked and it was empty)
But when I'm running

```
torch.multinomial(out_probs, 1)
```

I'm getting :

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: invalid multinomial distribution (encountering probability entry < 0) at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorRandom.cpp:325
```

That implies my tensor has a negative entry and I don't know why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you've found a bug in the error reporting for `torch.multinomial`.

For example

```
x = torch.ones(128, 1)
x[0] *= 1e100
out_probs = F.softmax(x, dim=0)
print('Negative values:', torch.sum(out_probs < 0).item())
y = torch.multinomial(out_probs, 1)
```

results in the following output

```
Negative values: 0
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: invalid multinomial distribution (encountering probability entry < 0) at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorRandom.cpp:298
```

It turns out this is getting triggered because `out_probs` contains `nan` entries.

```
print('nan values:', torch.sum(torch.isnan(out_probs)).item())
```

gives

```
nan values: 128
```

Which are caused by mathematical instabilities in softmax.

Strangely, when the values in `out_probs` are infinite you get the proper error message

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: invalid multinomial distribution (encountering probability entry = infinity or NaN) at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorRandom.cpp:302
```

This bug should probably be reported at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues if it hasn't been fixed in the most recent version.

By the way I'm using PyTorch 1.0.1.post2